# Android GoogleMaps slow onMapClick response

Tags: android, google-maps

I set a click listener (GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener) for GoogleMap object in the `onMapReady()` method like this.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    addClickListener(map);
}
```

Here is the addClickListener():

```
private void addClickListener(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            Log.d("ON_MAP_CLICK", "1. OnMapClick called");
            handleOnMapClick(point);
        }
    });
}
```

Since I set the map ready in the onMapReady method it is logical that I also add the click listener there.

The problem is that the delay for clicking on the map and the code to register that click is around 1 second while is should be instant.

**Problem**: The problem is not the time it takes to call addClickListener(GoogleMap) but the time that onMapClick() registers a click on the map (around 1 second).

Why is it so slow?

I am using GoogleMap V2

Thanks!

Comment: Code is looking like problemless. If you are debugging the app, it can cause  delays.

Comment: The feedback came from the users and so I am looking for ways to make the onMapClick() register the click faster. Don't have a clue why it takes so much time. Is there a benchmark maybe that will tell how long it should take.?

Comment: @KasparTr were you ever able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that addClickListener method is called after 1 second because onMapReady call back will called only after intializing the map. So it take some delay initially for calling your addClickListener method.

So you will observe this delay only for the first time not all the time and it is working as like it is expected,  No changes required in your code

Comment: Please see edits. The problem is the onMapClick() not registering a click fast enough not when the addClickListener(GoogleMap) is called.

Answer (score 0):

onMapReady will call after the map is initialized, i had a project that took a while to load the map making all the functions "slow".
You can try to load the map earlier to prevent that by adding this to the Splashscreen or Activity.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MapView mv = new MapView(getApplicationContext());
                    mv.onCreate(null);
                    mv.onPause();
                    mv.onDestroy();
                }catch (Exception ignored){

                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Please see edits. The problem is the onMapClick() not registering a click fast enough not when the addClickListener(GoogleMap) is called.